# VSCode Extension Help: How can I retrieve the content of all "find highlights"? editor.action.selectHighlights only seems to work when in Regex mode

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I need to retrieve the text of all "find occurrences" in the active editor. By "find occurrences" I mean the highlighted matches that appear when you search in the find widget.

I've tried executing `await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.selectHighlights');`, but mysteriously this only seems to work when the find widget is in regex mode.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a VSCode extension (Using Typescript) - How can I get the text content of all matches when the user executes a search in the Find Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78242034/in-a-vscode-extension-using-typescript-how-can-i-get-the-text-content-of-all)